# How Can I Edit the Registration Code?

Tags: php, user-registration

I would like to add a group of two radio buttons to Wordpress's registration page (yes and no), where if yes is selected the value in the email field will be added to an aweber mailing list.

Would this be best achieved by editing the registration code itself? If so, what .php file could I find the relevant code in? Or is there a plugin that could do this more easily?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the plugin [AWeber Web Form Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/aweber-web-form-widget). Just enable aweber optin checkbox for registration.

Or

If you want to do it yourself checkout the article http://adamcap.com/2011/10/how-to-integrate-aweber-and-wordpress-registration-without-a-plugin/

Comment: @Arw50452 if it helps you, mark this answer as correct.